# Why this RewriteRule needs the flag [L]

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

With this config

```
<Directory "/path/to/www">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule "^v1(.*)$" "v2$1" [L]
    RewriteRule "^v2(.*)$" "/v3$1" [R=301]
</Directory>
```

http://localhost/v1/file.txt redirects to http://localhost/v3/file.txt

But without the [L] flag, the same url redirects to http://localhost/v3/file.txt/file.txt

I don't know why.

`v3/file.txt/file.txt` is strange, why the filename is duplicated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

In other words, [L] breaks the chain, otherwise, the next rule will be applied.

Comment: yes, and in both cases the second rule is applied, that's why the URI is v3 instead of v2. But I don't know why in the second case the filename is duplicated

Comment: $1 = the uri, the first rewrite transform it from v1/file.txt to v2/file.txt, the second rule transform whatever starts by v2 to v3/{URI}, in this case v3/file.txt/file.txt

Comment: Why this doesn't duplicate the filename: `RewriteRule "^(.*)v1$" "$1v2"` and `RewriteRule "^(.*)v2$" "/$1v3" [R=301] `. The uri path/file.v1 redirects to path/file.v3